# Creating a new field having the same type as selected field?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I set up a `QgsFieldComboBox` for a Plugin. I know I can read the selected fieldname the following:

```
self.dlg.MyQgsFieldComboBox.currentField()
```

[Studying the docs](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/gui/Field/QgsFieldComboBox.html), I cannot find an option to read the currentFieldType() directly. So I know I can get field types of my selected layer the following:

```
self.mylayerfieldtypes = [field.typeName() for field in self.myselectedlayer.fields()]
```

I could stitch this together the following, to get the field type only of my selected field:

```
myfieldname = self.dlg.MyQgsFieldComboBox.currentField()

for field in self.myselectedlayer.fields():
   if field.name() == myfieldname:
       myfieldtype = field.typeName()
```

But my issue now is, when creating a new layer having a field with the same type as my selected field, I cannot just use `myfieldtype` for it like

```
QgsField("MyNewFieldHavingTheSameTypeAsMyOldField", myfieldtype)
```

How can I create a new field, having the same type as my selected field? Copying the field to my new layer is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the answer is just too simple: instead of `field.typeName()` just use `field.type()`.

```
myfieldname = self.dlg.MyQgsFieldComboBox.currentField()

for field in self.myselectedlayer.fields():
   if field.name() == myfieldname:
       myfieldtype = field.type()
QgsField("MyNewFieldHavingTheSameTypeAsMyOldField", myfieldtype)
```